# Raspberry PI will not boot unless I apply pressure to SD card

Tags: hardware, sd-card

I have several Raspberry Pis that need extra pressure on the SD card in order to boot up. I have a temporary fix that involves scraps of envelope flaps glued onto the card but they become unstuck over time. Does anyone have a better method of maintaining pin contact with their SD cards?

Pins look normal to me.
[image: Pins]

Paper trick
[image: Paper trick which sometimes works]

Comment: On a Pi where the holder broke I glued a bit of plastic on top and, like you, use a bit of paper to hold the SD card securely.

Comment: You could replace the slot? It's a bit of a fiddly job requiring soldering, but replacement slots are available from, for example 4tronix.co.uk. I've had to do this a few times and it's delicate work.

Comment: Could you supply a picture of your SD card slot?

Comment: I had to resort to the paper-hack on a Point-and-shoot camera too, working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw someone else posted this as a temporary fix but for me it is going to be permanent.

$3 clamp

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to try to fix this:

1) If the pins are bent out of position you can use a needle to carefully bend them back.

2) You can stack the card with something. Thin plastic cut from a plastic folder is probably better than paper.

3) If nothing else works, you have to replace the slot.

If you suspect this is a result of tear because you insert and remove the SD-card a lot, I would suggest getting micro SD-cards and micro SD-card adapters. This would allow you to replace the (micro) SD-card without causing tear on your SD-card slot.

Comment: Using micro SD-cards is a good idea. Thanks for sharing. +1