# Same SD card working in one PI but not in another

Tags: boot, boot-issues

One month before my Raspbian Pi was working properly with a SD card and it stopped working from Yesterday.When i give supply to Raspbian Pi,the Red light is constantly glowing but green light flashing continuously  and no booting of SD card.

When i insert the same SD card in another new PI ,it works properly.

If anyone knows the answer Please help me.

Comment: Check that the SD card is properly seated in the holder.  It sounds like a loose or intermittent connection.

Comment: Adding to joan's comment, see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23034/raspberry-pi-will-not-boot-unless-i-apply-pressure-to-sd-card/23039#23039 as a possible cause.

Comment: I have two sd cards and two raspberries, model 3B+ and model 2. I was trying to use the sd card from model 2 in model 3B+ and the rasperry is not reading from it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Several reasons

- Check the SD Card slot, maybe you need to push it in further
- Maybe the charger is dying and isn't giving the Pi sufficient power
- The Pi is broken

Answer (score 2):

I have had a (mechanical) problem with one SD card: it would work in one, but not in another Pi. In fact, I could install everything on the problem card and it would run for a couple of hours, but then, out of the blue started posting messages that looked like corruption of the file system.

I turned out that the problem card (Transcend SD HC 8GB class 10) was slightly bent on the side where the contacts are located. If I put it down on a flat surface with the contacts down, the center of the plastic was slightly higher then the sides. The other side of the plastic cover was flat. I assume the overall thickness of the plastic is less on the contacts side (and even not symmetrical) making this possible.

I am pretty sure that it was not caused by any abuse or ill-treatment, but somehow a result of the manufacturing/construction process.

After having slightly heated the plastic at the contact side end of the back (on the label side, not on the side of the contacts) and applying some force to straighten it (keeping pressure for a while), the card is now working without problems in *both* Pi's.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possibility that the one RPi is really broken or bricked for that matter (could anything be said about the history of usage for that device, e.g. over-voltage on supply or GPIO-Pins?) one other problem could be the electrical contacting of the card in the holder. Problems and issues with that have been reported frequently for the RPi especially when removing and inserting the card often. See [Raspberry PI will not boot unless I apply pressure to SD card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23034/raspberry-pi-will-not-boot-unless-i-apply-pressure-to-sd-card/23039#23039) for workarounds to check whether a not properly connected card is the cause of the problem.